# Grails: Creating classes that you do not want to store on the DB

Tags: grails, groovy, web-applications, grails-domain-class

In grails is creating a new domain class and never persisting any objects to the db, the best way to create a class that you don't want to store in the db?

Comment: Well apart from the answer given, you can try Command objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

define `static mapWith="none"` inside your class in grails-app/domain folder

Comment: Did not know this option. nice!

Answer (score 11):

Grails provide the `src` directory to develop some utility classes and other artifacts. The `src` directory it not persisted.

```
src - Supporting sources
    groovy - Other Groovy sources
    java - Other Java sources
```